Am I using continue wrong?
One of the tasks in my task book is to output the continents from the list and skip Antarctica.
I wanted to do that with continue and a for loop:
continents = ["Afrika", "Antarktis", "Asien", "Australien und Ozeanien", "Europa", "Nordamerika", "Südamerika"]
for continent in continents:
    if continent == "Antarktis":
        continue
    print(continents)

The outcome is always the whole list.

You're using it correctly, then for some reason printing the whole list.

print(continents) should be print(continent)

How can that be? I have entered the code in Pycharm as it appears here

you are encountering this  because you're printing the entire list (continents) instead of the individual continent variable inside the loop.
continents = ["Afrika", "Antarktis", "Asien", "Australien und Ozeanien", "Europa", "Nordamerika", "Südamerika"]
for continent in continents:
    if continent == "Antarktis":
        continue
    print(continent)  

output:-
Afrika
Asien
Australien und Ozeanien
Europa
Nordamerika
Südamerika


Seems logical to me, but i tried it and than the outcome is "Südamerika"

@Shadowheart What do you mean "the outcome is 'Südamerika' "? There should be multiple lines of output, and that's just the last one.

@wjandrea but its not. It just says "Südamerika". I dont know why it only print the last object from the list...

@Shadowheart Oh, did you mess up the indentation? The print needs to be inside the loop. If you unindented it, that would put it outside the loop and you would only see the last value of the loop variable (i.e. "Südamerika").

@Shadowheart To help clarify, what output were you originally getting? The code you posted in the question results in the list printed multiple times, but if the indentation was wrong in your real code, you would only see the list printed once.

@wjandrea yes, the indentation was the problem. Thank you very much!
